# How Can I bypass CORS to bubble an error back to the client after an ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an ajax call with a `done` and `fail` leg:

```
$.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + "/auth/sign-in",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: loginFormData,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}

        })…..
```

and the fail function declared in the form `.fail(function (xhr, status, error) {`

In my startup.cs file when adding the CORS service, I'm setting it up in this way:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                 builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials()
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "HEAD")
                .WithHeaders("Acccept", "Accept-Language", "Content-Language", "Content-Type", "Last-Event-ID")
                .Build());
        });
```

In my Web Api Method I raise an error back:

```
 Exception inner = new Exception { Source = "WebApi: Authorisation" };
 throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You must login",inner);
```

the code drops back into the fail function of the ajax call but error is empty. In the Browser (Chrome) I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:54981/auth/sign-in' from origin 'http://localhost:54979' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Need to allow OPTIONS method also. Your POST will generate a preflight OPTIONS request by the browser before the actual POST is sent. Also useless setting access control headers in the request

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is not sending the CORS Header when there is an uncaught Exception. You have to configure that.

See following issuecomment on github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2378#issuecomment-354673591

Additionally, you are sending the header

```
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

from the client to the server, which is wrong. It should be sent from the server to the client.

Comment: I didn't have any headers set on my Ajax call originally with CORS only being set from my startup file as above, but I still receive this error. How would I add that to an exception being raised from the srver?

Comment: The cors header on your ajax request has nothing to do with your error. It is just wrong.

Comment: So I remove the `headers` attribute` from the ajax request. As you can see from my original question, on the server side I'm adding the headers, but I still get the same error. No Idea why someone wants to down vote my question. It's a valid issue for me, I've shown my code and I've researched without finding a valid working example of what I should do.